# Create an enum with parameter

Tags: swift, enums, output, enumeration

I have some Outputs in my code so I regrouped all that with an Enum String.

The problem is that I have some Outputs containing variable.

Is It possible to create an Enum who takes variable ?

Exemple with this string

```
print("The name of the Team is \(team.name)")
```

I wanted to do something like that:

```
enum Exemple: String {
    case TEAM_NAME(name: String) = "The name of the Team is \(name)"}

print(Exemple.TEAM.NAME("Team 1").rawvalue)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can define an instance method or computed property for enum that will return a string value in depend of enumeration case and associated value. See example for playground.

```
enum Example {
    case firstItem
    case secondItem(withText: String)

    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .firstItem: return "Simple string"
        case .secondItem(withText: let text): return "String with additional text: \(text)"
        }
    }
}

let myEnumItem: Example = .secondItem(withText: "Test")
let text = myEnumItem.stringValue
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have an enum with associated values for cases. But in order to get the output you're looking for you will need a function.

```
enum Example {

    case teamName(name: String)
    case teamId(id: Int)

    func printName() {
        switch self {
        case .teamName(name: let name):
            print(name)
        default:
             break
        }
    }
}

let team = Example.teamName(name: "team1")
team.printName() // prints team1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for Enum to have both raw value and associated value. I think you can get by with the associated value. Without the raw value the enum still can provide you enough information to compose the message